# Match first two characters and replace whole word with new value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I need some help in find and replace using regular expression.

In my project I want to match the hex color code value by 2 characters on start and need to replace the whole color code value with some new value. I tried following code but it does not giving me required output. Whatever I have tried is as follows.

```
let str = '<path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#9F6853;" d="M578.154,690.683
        c58.702-39.067,85.337-134.776,72.948-190.814C673.44,558.122,670.446,662.764,578.154,690.683z"/>
    <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#9F6853;" d="M659.886,459.995c-17.96-18.14-35.918-51.26-50.976-72.373
        c-15.351-21.524-33.064-37.037-66.514-37.725C616.591,331.003,627.848,404.626,659.886,459.995z"/>';
let re = /^#9/g;
let subst = '#ff4040';  
let result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

I am expecting following output.

```
<path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff4040;" d="M578.154,690.683
            c58.702-39.067,85.337-134.776,72.948-190.814C673.44,558.122,670.446,662.764,578.154,690.683z"/>
        <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#ff4040;" d="M659.886,459.995c-17.96-18.14-35.918-51.26-50.976-72.373
            c-15.351-21.524-33.064-37.037-66.514-37.725C616.591,331.003,627.848,404.626,659.886,459.995z"/>
```

Please help me in this as I am stucked at this. I tried lot of things but still facing same issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `#9[a-fA-F0-9]+\b`

Or for 3 or 6 chars and using a case insensitive match using `/i`

```
#9(?:[a-f0-9]{2}|#9[a-f0-9]{5})\b
```

```js
let str = `<path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#9F6853;" d="M578.154,690.683
    c58.702-39.067,85.337-134.776,72.948-190.814C673.44,558.122,670.446,662.764,578.154,690.683z"/>
    <path style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;fill:#9F6853;" d="M659.886,459.995c-17.96-18.14-35.918-51.26-50.976-72.373
    c-15.351-21.524-33.064-37.037-66.514-37.725C616.591,331.003,627.848,404.626,659.886,459.995z"/>`;
let re = /#9[a-f0-9]+\b/ig;
let subst = '#ff4040';
let result = str.replace(re, subst);
console.log(result);
```